# Adding Class to selected button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using this button group structure. Now I need to add class active to each button when I click on it. And remove from it when I click on another button.  This is my HTML structure, is something like that:

```html
<div id="donation-pricecontainer" class="section donation">
  <h3>Select a contribution amount.</h3>
  <div class="field button 18294784 required btn-float"><label for="18294784"><button id="18294784" name="donation-level" class="required" type="button" value="50.000000" maxlength="255">$50<span class="label btn-value">$50.00 - test</span></button></label></div>
  <div class="field button 18294785 required btn-float"><label for="18294785"><button id="18294785" name="donation-level" class="required" type="button" value="100.000000" maxlength="255">$100<span class="label btn-value">$100.00 - test</span></button></label></div>
  <div class="field button 18294786 required btn-float"><label for="18294786"><button id="18294786" name="donation-level" class="required" type="button" value="500.000000" maxlength="255">$500<span class="label btn-value">$500.00 - test</span></button></label></div>
  <div class="field button 18294787 required btn-float"><label for="18294787"><button id="18294787" name="donation-level" class="required" type="button" value="1000.000000" maxlength="255">$1,000<span class="label btn-value">$1,000.00 - test</span></button></label></div>
  <div class="field button 18294788 required btn-float"><label for="18294788"><button id="18294788" name="donation-level" class="required" type="button" value="2000.000000" maxlength="255">$2,000<span class="label btn-value">$2,000.00 - test</span></button></label></div>
  <div class="field radio other-option required other-btn"><label for="other-option"><input id="other-option" name="donation-level" class="required" type="button" maxlength="255"><span class="label">Or choose your own amount.</span></label></div>
  <div class="field text other-amount"><input id="other-amount" name="other-amount" class="otherAmount" type="text" placeholder="$0.00"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: We are always glad to help and support new coders but you need to help yourself first. After [doing more research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527), if you have a problem, please post what you've tried with a clear explanation of what isn't working and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read ['How to Ask a good question' guide](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [Question Do's and Don'ts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527), and [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way:

```
$("button[class=required]").click(function (e) {
   $("#" + e.currentTarget.id).addClass("selected");
   $("button[id!=" + e.currentTarget.id+"]").removeClass("selected")
})
```

On click I select a button and I set a new class on it, if I click the second time the same button, the button become default without new class

Comment: Please see Rory's comment on the question.  People are expected to help themselves in the first instance.

Comment: I don't care, I understood what he meant and I answered his question

Comment: No need to be rude, just trying to save you downvotes as people tend to downvote answers to questions like this, because `$(this).addClass("selected").siblings().removeClass("selected")` is trivial.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this simple code pattern , initially on click removing the active class from all button and then add active to the clicked one

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".btn").click(function(){
$(".btn").removeClass("active");
$(this).addClass("active")
})
})
```

```css
.active{
background:red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn">btn</button>
<button class="btn">btn</button>
<button class="btn">btn</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not fairly a good question but I still want to try to help. Firstly you have to learn is how to add/remove/toggle class of a specify dom. In your case, it is a button. Please check this doc.https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList.

Next, you have to learn how to programing to resolve nature problems. In your case, every time a button is clicked,  it's required to know the activated button previously and remove the class. And then add the class to the current button.

That's all you need to know about it. Go translate them to real code,  you must do it by your self.